# android: sending a push notification using GCM to all the devices instead of only 1000

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Hi i'm developing a news android app, and i want to send a push notification to all the registered devices, but apparently Google said in their tutorials that you can send a push notification to up to 1000 users. but this is very frustrating and i know apps that send push notifications to all their users.

I'm very confused about this and i have been looking for a solution for three days now, is there a clear way to send a push notification to all app-registered devices or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit in sending the notification to the number of user.

GCM allows us to attach a message to 1000 users at a time. This doesn't mean there is a limit to the gcm notification

Refer this

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#multicast

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer, so how can i send a notification to all my users ?

Comment: You need to write server side code to send notification to all the users registration Id which are configured with you

Comment: i know that, let's say i have 1,000,000 registered users, i have to make 1000 curl calls, each call contains 1000 IDs ?

Comment: Yes.. 1000 calls for 1000 id for 1lakh users

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on sending out push notifications in large quantities and to large user groups you should consider using a back-end service to simplify your life. Parse is one option. You can send push notifications to all of your users or even send out custom notifications based on certain conditions. You can find more information here:

https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: Thanks, i don't know why i didn't use that in the first place :-), can you please up vote my question because somebody down voted the question for no reason!